# File Upload in WebdriverIO where we need to access the file explorer in Windows

Tags: javascript, file-upload, webdriver-io, asyncfileupload

This is a field where either I have to access the file explorer in Windows and then select the file to upload or, I have to drag and drop the file to upload the file. I am using the following code in WebdriverIO, but the file upload in not happening.

```
 const fileUpload = $("//div[@id='customer_information']//div[@aria-hidden='true']");
 const path = require('path');
 const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../Test Data/Captute0.png');
 //const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'F:\\WebDriverIO\\Capture.png');
 fileUpload.setValue(filePath);
```